# @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation with class prameter is not initializing properties object

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i  have following @CongfigurationProperties class

```
//@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource("classpath:typesofcharge.properties")
public class ChargeProperties {
    private HashMap<String,String> charge=new HashMap<>();
    public HashMap<String,String> getCharge()
    {
        return this.charge;
    }

}
```

And this is my Configuration file

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.vehiclemanagement.config,com.vehiclemanagement.client,"
        + "com.vehiclemanagement.controller,"
        + "com.vehiclemanagement.exception,"
        + "com.vehiclemanagement.model,"
        + "com.vehiclemanagement.service"})
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ChargeProperties.class)
public class VehicleManagementConfig {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(VehicleManagementConfig.class, args);
    }

}
```

If i use @Component annotation in ChargeProperties and remove ChargeProperties.class annotation in Configuration class the charge HashMap is  initialized properly

If i remove @Component and pass ChargeProperties.class as argument  like this 
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ChargeProperties.class) like how document says the charge HashMap is empty when i run

I am using spring boot 2.0.2 release .But i am following latest docs. Can anyone explain why this are not working as document suggest

content of property file is as follows

**UPDATE** the content of property files are as shown

```
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE
charge.peak=Double_rate;
charge.lateNight=duration_based_charge;
charge.earlyMorning=special_offers;
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53815159/how-to-autowire-configuration-property-class-bean-or-component-in-spring-boot-ap).

Comment: @M.Deinum i deleted old question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we use @PropertySource we have to use component otherwise the properties will not be read

since we added the @ComponentScan We don't have to mention @EnableConfiguationProperties annotation at all The propety class object can be autowired as Bean

Answer (score 1):

When specifying `ChargeProperies.class` on the `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation it will be registered as a bean through the `EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector` class inside `@EnableConfigurationProperties`.

So in the example, if you have only annotated the `ChargeProperties` class with `@ConfigurationProperties` it will create a `chargeProperties` bean with an empty charge `HashMap` because it defaulted back to application.properties as the source.

A custom source can be specified by using `@PropertySource`.

> @PropertySource annotation providing a convenient and declarative mechanism for adding
>   a PropertySource to Spring's Environment. To be used in conjunction
>   with @Configuration classes.

As per documentation above, to use `@PropertySource` to load the custom source, one has to use the `@Configuration` annotation.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:typesofcharge.properties")
```

Under the hood a `@Configuration` class is a `@Component`.

```
@Target(value=TYPE)
 @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
 @Documented
 @Component
public @interface Configuration
```

So to your question. By specifying a custom `@PropertySource` without `@Configuration`, spring did not load the properties in the `@PropertySource` annotation and defaulted back to the application.properties.

Comment: My question is why charge HashMap is not initialized without Component annotation

Comment: I think it is because `@PropertySource` needs to be used in conjunction with `@Configuration`. I have modified my answer to include the documentation when using `@PropertySource`

Comment: I modified my answer to address your question; why the charge `HashMap` is empty.